# Continuity of $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}\sin(x^2+y^2)$ if $y\neq 0$,$ f(x,0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

This function is continuous in $c=(x,y)$  when $y\neq0$ and it is not continuous when $y=0$ and $\sin x^2 \neq 0$. I think it is also not continuous when $y=0$ and $\sin(x^2) = 0$ , particularly  at $(0,0)$. However, in this case, I can´t find a subset for which  the limit is different from $0$. I know there are other ways to prove this, but it would be much easier if I could find a proper set. Can you help me?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the function is not continuous when $x=\sqrt{\pi/2}$ (meaning $\sin^2x\ne 0$) and $y\to 0$

Comment: Look again, the square is over the $x$ not the $\sin$. I'll add some parentheses to make it clearer though

Comment: So at that point $x^2=\pi/2$, the sine term is equal to $1$, and $x/y\to (\pi/2)/0=\infty$

Comment: Yeah sorry, then it's also discontinuous. I will edit

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$f(x,y)=\frac xy\sin(x^2+y^2)=$$
$$x\sin(x^2)\frac{\cos(y^2)}{y}+x\frac{\sin(y^2)}{y}\cos(x^2)$$

$$f(x,x^3)\to 1$$ and $$f(x,-x^3)\to -1$$

Comment: This is OK for (0,0), what should I do in other cases?

Comment: @Seven As you said, its continuous if $y\ne $ and at $(x,0) $ if $x\ne 0$.

Comment: And when $\sin(x^2)= 0$?

Comment: You can't take $y=x^3$ in the general case because the point has to be a cluster point of the set chosen